# LLBLGenPro: Query a blank space

Tags: c#, llblgenpro

I am trying to query black spaces in the database using LLBL Gen Pro. 
Some in the database, the value is a blank (not null). 
Can someone tell me how do I do it?

I have tried a few way, but none of them works correctly.

```
filter.AddWithAnd(RecipeFields.FeaturedItem % ""); //way 1

filter.AddWithAnd(RecipeFields.FeaturedItem == String.empty); // way 2

filter.AddWithAnd(RecipeFields.FeaturedItem == System.DBNull.value); // way 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it should work:

```
var predicateBucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
var trimedLengthPredicate = new EntityField("FeaturedItemEmptyLength", 
            new DbFunctionCall("LENGTH", new Object() { new DbFunctionCall("RTRIM", new Object() { new DbFunctionCall("LTRIM", new Object() { RecipeFields.FeaturedItem })})})) == 0;
var emptryTextPredicate = RecipeFields.FeaturedItem % "% %";
predicateBucket.PredicateExpression.Add(trimedLengthPredicate & emptryTextPredicate);
```

Which is a predicate for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM RecipeFields r WHERE LENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(r.FeaturedItem))) = 0 AND r.FeaturedItem LIKE '% %';
```

*Warning: This predicate checks only for **space**, not TAB or Enter characters.*

For more info: https://www.llblgen.com/tinyforum/Messages.aspx?ThreadID=23385